# Double array method error: Incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java, arrays, double

I'm trying to input a `double` array but I'm getting an error message in my code

```
public static double getHighNumber(double[] numbers) {
    int a, b, t;

    for (a = 2; a < 11; a++) {
        for (b = 10; b + 1 >= a; b--) {
            if (numbers[b - 1] > numbers[b]) {
                t = numbers[b - 1];
                numbers[b - 1] = numbers[b];
                numbers[b] = t;
            }
        }
    }
    return numbers[10];
}
```

on the line `t = numbers[b-1];`

It compiles and works properly if I use `int` arrays but not `double` arrays. How can I change the method so it accepts `double` arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numbers` is a `double`, `t` should be too (based on your code, that will make `t = numbers[b-1];` *valid*). Something like,

```
int a, b; // , t;
double t;
```

**but**, if you just want the highest number; then you could do something like

```
public static double getHighNumber(double[] numbers) {
    double h = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        h = Math.max(h, numbers[i]);
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Ah it worked, thanks! Didn't know about Math.max, thanks for that piece of advice too :)